# Why does my printed equation keep printing the same number?

Tags: java

I am trying to make an adding game but my randomly generated numbers to be added are not random even though I assigned them to be random each time. Someone help please. I'm still working on my project but am stuck on this part. My code so far:

```
package addgame;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public  class add {
    private static Scanner console;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                "We are going to play an adding game. Type your answer.");
        equation();

    }

    public static void Answer(Scanner console) {

    }

    public static void equation() {
        int tries = 0;
        while (tries == 0) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int nums = rand.nextInt(25) + 6;
            int totalnums = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
            int sumAns = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalnums + 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(nums + "+ ");
                sumAns += nums;

            }
            System.out.print("= ");

            console = new Scanner(System.in);
            int ans = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println(sumAns);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your observed vs. expected output? Also, don't re-create the Random object within the while loop. Create this object once.

Comment: "*...my randomly generated numbers to be added are not random*" they are random, but you are simply randomizing once per loop in which you ask user for result so you are having `x+x+x` instead of `x+y+z`.

Comment: It also appears that your `while` loop is never-ending. You don't have `break` anywhere and `tries` never changes (making it a redundant variable)

Comment: the output will be the sum of the numbers so it is what sumAns will be. I have a print statement at the end because I was testing something. The problem is that when I generate an addition problem a random number will be generated but it will be like "18+18+18=" or "6+6+6+6=" and I dont know why it is doing that.

Comment: Which part of your code makes you think that output you are getting should be different then `18+18+18=`?

Comment: System.out.print(nums + "+ "); shouldnt nums be different each time i increments?

Comment: how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: How about generating the random numbers inside the for-loop that prints them?

Comment: ya thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You must put the randomizer inside the `for-loop`:

```
    private static Scanner console;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                "We are going to play an adding game. Type your answer.");
        equation();

    }

    public static void Answer(Scanner console) {

    }

    public static void equation() {
        int tries = 0;
        while (tries == 0) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int nums = 0;
            int totalnums = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
            int sumAns = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalnums + 1; i++) {
                nums = rand.nextInt(25) + 6; //Changed
                System.out.print(nums + "+ ");
                sumAns += nums;

            }
            System.out.print("= ");

            console = new Scanner(System.in);
            int ans = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println(sumAns);
        }
    }
}
```